# плавное вращение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Все работает хорошо, но нужно, чтобы вращение было более плавно. Вроде использовал Lerp, но этого недостаточно. Поворот все равно получается немного резким.

```
public class rotateCamera : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
    {

        Vector2 delta;
        Quaternion originRotation;
        GameObject player;

        Quaternion targetRot;

        private void Start()
        {
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
        }

        public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {

            delta = eventData.delta;

                delta.x = Mathf.Clamp(delta.x, -3f, 3f);
                delta.y = Mathf.Clamp(delta.y, -1.5f, 1.5f);

            originRotation = player.transform.rotation;

        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {

            targetRot = originRotation * Quaternion.Euler(-delta.y, delta.x, 0f);
            player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRot, 1f);
            player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);



        }

    }
```

Comment: а если это делать в `Update`, а не `FixedUpdate` ? Хотя вообще для камеры обычно все пишут в `LateUpdate`

Comment: Использовал он Lerp, ага, с параметром 1f, это тоже самое, что без него.

Answer (score 1):

Для поворотов используют Quaternion.Slerp https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html)
Как вариант - запоминаете начальное и конечное положение, а затем постепенно увеличиваете третий параметр (что у lerp, что и у Slerp) range [0, 1] - 0 - это начальное положение, 1 - полный поворот до конечного положения, соответственно какая нужна скорость прогресса, такую переменную и ставите. Если не запоминать начальное положение, то Lerp и Slerp будут "затухать" при "подходе" к цели. Если будете делать в Update, то не забывайте умножать на Time.deltaTime, а вообще всё это можно вынести в корутину.